# Conjugate vertices and distinguishing properties

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

#### Motivation (added)

A finite $n$-set is uniquely described (up to isomorphism) by a single population number $n$.

A finite $n$-set with $k$ predicates is uniquely described (up to isomorphism) by $2^k$ population numbers $n_i$, corresponding to the $2^k$ combinations of predicates, $\sum_{i=1}^{2^k} n_i = n$

A finite $n$-set with 1 binary relation (a graph $G$) can be uniquely described (up to isomorphism) by $k$ population numbers $n_i$, corresponding to its $k$ $Aut(G)$-orbits, provided these are appropriately described, $\sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i = n$.

I want to clarify what an appropriate description of the orbits might be and whether there is something like a canonical description of the orbits.

#### Definition 1

Let $v$, $w$ be vertices of a finite graph $G$. $v$ and $w$ are **conjugate** ($v \sim w$) iff there is a $g \in Aut(G)$ with $g(v) = w$.

#### *Question 1 (postponed)*

*Is there an official and more common name for this equivalence? (Comment: I formerly called it "equivalent" but already changed this to "conjugate", thanks to Pete's hint.)*

#### Definition 2 (third revision)

Let $G$ be a graph, $v \in V(G)$ and $\phi_v(x)$ be a first order vertex property (formulated in the first order language of graphs) such that $(\forall w \in V(G)\ )\phi_v(w) \Leftrightarrow v \sim w$.

Let $\lbrace \phi_v(x)\rbrace_{[v] \in G/_\sim}$ be a family of such properties.

If all graphs $H$ for which there is a bijection $f:V(G)\rightarrow V(H)$ with

$\phi_v(x) \Leftrightarrow \phi_v(f(x))$ for all $[v] \in G/_\sim$

are isomorphic to $G$, we call the family of properties $\lbrace \phi_v(x)\rbrace_{[v] \in G/_\sim}$ **distinguishing with respect to $G$**.

*(Comment: I added **w.r.t $G$** to make things clearer and to be more precise.)*

#### Claim

Given a graph $G$ and a distinguishing family of properties w.r.t. $G$ then the population function $f: \lbrace \phi_v(x)\rbrace_{[v] \in G/_\sim} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with $f(\phi_v(x)) = |[v]|$ determines the graph up to isomorphism.

#### Definition 2a (added)

A distinguishing family of properties is **minimal** if its overall number of bound variables is minimal.

*(Comment: Minimal distinguishing properties might serve as a canonical form of a graph.)*

#### Question 2

Is there an official and more common name for distinguishing properties?

#### Question 3 (second revision)

Can a distinguishing family of properties be computed from the adjacency matrix in linear time? Or is this problem provably as hard as graph isomorphism?

*Addendum:* As pointed out in the second answer (Mariano's) it is straight forward to begin with a complete description of the graph (one existential formula, stating that there are exactly $n$ different vertices and their relations) and make successively each single variable free. In the resulting $|G|$ formulas one then has to find the orbits (= equivalent formulas) which is probably as hard as graph isomorphism.

#### Question 3a (added)

Can a *minimal* distinguishing family of properties be computed from the adjacency matrix in linear time? Or is this problem provably as hard as graph isomorphism?

#### *Question 4 (postponed)*

*Which language $L$ is appropriate? Can it always be the language of first order logic with a graph specific signature?*

#### Addendum: Example

The family of properties with the single member $\phi(x)$ = "x has exactly one neighbour" together with the number of vertices that share this property - 2 - fix $K_2$

#### Addendum: More examples

Definitions:

1. Let a *d-neighbour of x* be a vertex *d* edges away from *x*.
2. Let $\phi_d^n$ stand for *x has exactly n d-neighbours*.
3. Let $C_l^n$ be the graph consisting of *n* cycles of lenght $l, l \geq 2$, $C_2^1 = K_2$.
4. Let $P_l$ be the path graph of length $l$.

#### (1)

Consider the vertex transitive graphs $C_2^n$.

For each $C$ of them the one-element (vertex transitivity!) family of properties $\lbrace \phi_1^1 \rbrace$ is distinguishing w.r.t. $C$.

#### (2)

Consider the vertex transitive graphs $C_l^1, l > 2$, $l$ prime or $l = 4$.

For each $C$ of them the one-element family of properties $\lbrace \phi_1^2 \rbrace$ is distinguishing w.r.t. $C$.

For $C = C_3^2$ (vertex transitive, too) $\lbrace \phi_1^2 \wedge \phi_2^0 \rbrace$ is distinguishing w.r.t. $C$.

For $C = C_6^1$ (vertex transitive, too) $\lbrace \phi_1^2 \wedge \phi_2^2 \rbrace$ is distinguishing w.r.t. $C$.

These examples seem to be easily expanded by combinatorical means.

#### (3)

Consider the path graphs $P_l$ with $\lceil \frac{l}{2} \rceil$ conjugacy classes of vertices. Let $\psi_d$ stand for *x has a d-neighbour with degree 1*. Then

$\lbrace \phi_1^1 \rbrace\ \cup\ \lbrace \phi_1^2 \wedge \psi_k \rbrace_{k = 1,..,\lceil \frac{l}{2} \rceil - 1}$

is a distinguishing family of properties (not necessarily minimal).

Comment: The property "x has exactly one neighbor" does not satisfy the defining condition _for all_ graphs: just because two vertices have exactly one neighbor does not mean they are conjugate.  If you want $\phi$ to have this property only with respect to a fixed graph $G$, you need to say so.

Comment: In the corrected version I hope to have said so.

Comment: Is there a non trivial example? 

Comment: I will provide some soon!

Comment: I wonder why this is CW...

Comment: Sorry? (What is CW?)

Comment: Now I found out: Yes, why is this CW? Was it me by accident?

Comment: Posts that are edited many times automatically become CW.  (I don't know why.)

Comment: So it was my "fault". Can I roll this back? 

Comment: Nope.  It's not really a big deal.

Comment: It is not  big deal to edit the question, but it becomes slightly inelegant rather fast to change what  is actually being asked in  question! The question has now become "how can one find the orbits of $Aut(G)$ efficiently?", which is quite unrelated to what was being ask originally...

Comment: I don't agree: the original question was how to find a distinguishing family of properties which by definition is in 1:1 correspondence with the orbits of $Aut(G)$. I only wanted to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you allow equality then it is trivial that every graph has a distinguishing famil of properties. Since you are considering the property "$v$ has exactly one neighbor", I think you *are* including equality...

Indeed, let $G$ be a graph, let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be its vertices, and let me construct a 'distinguishing property' $\phi$ for $v_1$: put $\phi=(\exists x_2,x_2,\dots,x_n)\Phi(v_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ with $\Phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ being the formula which says that all its arguments are distinct and that the $i$th and $j$th arguments are $\sim$-related iff the vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ are connected in the graph $G$.

Using formulas constructed like this, I think you can answer your (main?) question.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand your answer: where do you think do I include equality (and which kind of)? And if it should be trivial to construct a "distinguishing family of properties w.r.t to G" - as you point out - I would have to revise my definition since I did not want to pose a trivial question (see my Question 3).

Comment: @Hans: how do you express the property "$v$ has exactly one neighbor" formally?

Comment: there is an x with Rvx and for each y holds: Rvy -> x = y

Comment: Well, since you are using equality of vertices, you are indeed including equality in your language :) 

Comment: Thanks, Mariano, you are perfectly right, the first step is easy: to construct for each vertex a formula which holds for it and exactly those that are conjugate to it: Just take the full description and make free each single variable successively. The next steps are not so easy: to find the conjugate formulas (corresponding to conjugate vertices) and - last but not least - to find distinguishing formulas with a minimum number of variables. (I didn't mention this yet because I haven't seen that the question otherwise is trivial.)

Comment: One remark: I have used the $\sim$ sign for conjugacy, in your formula I would have written $Rvw$.

Comment: I do not know why you think it is hard to find the conjugate formulas... You just have to pick one representative for each conjugacy class and construct the corresponding formula. The complexity in finding the conjugacy class has absolutely nothing to do with 'distinguishing properties': it is just a hard problem. 

Comment: You say "just pick one representative for each conjugacy class": is this soft or hard (I do not know)?
If we have the conjugacy classes we also have the distinguishing properties. Why do you say the both have "absolute nothing to do" with each other?